# libcurl and curl_global_init() on multiple executable files

Tags: c, compilation, libcurl

I have to realize a bash script which perform 2 request in a loop with libcurl to a webserver.

The script has this structure:

```
while :
do
  ./callA
  sleep(50)
  ./callB
  sleep(10)
done
```

The binary code of callA and callB has this structure:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    ...

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(various settings...);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if(res != CURLE_OK) {
            //do something...
        }
        else {
            //handle error...
       }
    }

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_global_cleanup();

}
```

from the [libcurl documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html) I read:

> The program must initialize some of the libcurl functionality globally. That means it should be done exactly once, no matter how many times you intend to use the library. Once for your program's entire life time. This is done using  *curl_global_init()*

It is not clear, for me, if "program's entire life time" means that if I use libcurl in 2 separate executables programs I have anyway to declare once, for example in a separate file which figure as initializer. Or, instead, I have to define both in callA source code and callB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case **callA** and **callB** are two distinctly separate programs running in one process each and thus totally independent of each other.

They have one "life time" each and thus both should call `curl_global_init()`.